# stm32f070rbt6 Stack pointer invalid address problem

Tags: stack, stm32, iar, hal

I have currently changed to a new microcontroller, STM32F070RBT6, I have used the STM32CubeMx to set up the microcontroller, i currently have no code just HAL initialisation code, when i debug it comes up with error message saying " The stack pointer for stack 'CSTACK' (currently 0x20000E38) is outside the stack range (0x20000110 to 0x20000510)"

I have tried all today to find the error, thats why i created a new stm32cube project with only initialisation code to see if it was an error on my part or HALs, does anyone have any idea what is causing this error? I havn't provided code as the project only contains the startup file etc, I am also using IAR as the IDE

Comment: Could be check the STACK size defined in your linker file.

Comment: My first guess is that there is an overflow of the c-stack, but the information in the question is not enough to confirm or deny this.